Non Verified Domain as IdntifierUri for Azure B2C IEF Application
Problem
I am unable to configure the identifierUri of an Azure B2C Identity Experience Framework (IEF) Application to a URL that is not verified. Furthermore, I cannot verify the domain I need to add because it is because it is a third party's domain configured by the SAML Service Provider.
Context
In the deprecated AAD Graph App Manifest, you were able to set "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2 to allow non-verified domains. On Azure's documentation, they said

If you do not update the accessTokenAcceptedVersion to 2 you will receive an error message requiring a verified domain.

The relying party is a 3rd party and their IssuerUri is not a domain that I can control. So when I set the identifierUris to their URI, I get the error Failed to update {application-name} application. Error detail: Values of IdentifierUris property must use a verified domain of the organization or its subdomain.
Screenshot of error
How can I resolve this issue?

Could you edit your question and add Portal image where you are facing error?

@Sridevi i just added it

Could you confirm whether you updated accessTokenAcceptedVersion to 2 in app's manifest or not?

@Sridevi I was unable to set accessTokenAcceptedVersion in the Microsoft Graph App Manifest (New). It displayed  the error Failed to update {application-name} application. Error detail: The application was not found. If the application was just created, wait a few minutes and refresh the page. This application has existed for >15 minutes.

In Microsoft Graph App Manifest (New), accessTokenAcceptedVersion will be present as requestedAccessTokenVersion under api like this https://i.imgur.com/JoRql0V.png

@Sridevi this worked on one of the two applications. I then deleted the other application and created a new one, and it resolve the issue. Thanks for the help!

Hi @JustinMassey Any update?

The error occurs if missed enabling "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2 before configuring non-verified domain as identifier URI.
Initially, I too got same error when I tried to update identifier URI with non-verified domain value without enabling accessTokenAcceptedVersion :

To resolve the error, make sure to update accessTokenAcceptedVersion to 2 that will be renamed as requestedAccessTokenVersion in Microsoft Graph App Manifest (New).
When I tried to update identifier URI with non-verified domain after modifying requestedAccessTokenVersion value to 2, it worked like this:

If still the error persists, try creating new application and update in that to resolve the issue.
